# Unity3d: Using sbar in unity 2018.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, substance

I have just downloaded a [procedural road material](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/textures-materials/roads/procedural-road-materials-67823) asset from the asset store. But when I import i get this error. How can I use them?

Unity Version: 2018.1.0b6

I have downloaded substance in unity by Allegorithmic, but it still doesn't work. I am now downloading unity 2017.2 because built in support was still there at that version.

> Error:
>
> Assets/Road Materials/Road.sbsar: Built-in support for Substance Designer materials has been removed from Unity. To continue
> using Substance Designer materials, you will need to install
> Allegorithmic's external importer from the Asset Store.

Comment: Turns out that the importer was not working with 2018.1 beta, which works now

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried reading the error and doing what it says?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded substance in unity by Allegorithmic, but it still doesn't work. I am now downloading unity 2017.2 because built in support was still there at that version.

Comment: You should mention that in your OP then.